# Typescript generic related

Tags: typescript, generics

recently get into typescript world and saw sth confusing which is related to generic. I saw some code below. I know the <> after "Dispatch" is to describe the type of "Dispatch" but why there is the  ?

Does it act as the extra type information for describing T which is used in "action"? Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text and not images, as described in [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine this interface:

```
interface Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
    <T extends A>(action: T): T;
}
```

First of all, the interface `Dispatch` is generic in `A`, so you can specify `A` to get a concrete type from it.  The type `A` specified is [constrained](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be something assignable to `Action`, and if you don't specify the type it will [default](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `AnyAction`:

```
let actionDispatcher: Dispatch<Action>; //okay
let anyActionDispatcher: Dispatch; // Dispatch<AnyAction>
let badDispatcher: Dispatch<string>; // error!
// not an Action ---------> ~~~~~~

interface FooAction extends Action {
    foo: string;
}

let fooDispatcher: Dispatch<FooAction>; // okay
```

---

So once you specify `A`, you get a concrete type by replacing all instances of `A` with the type you specify.  Let's look at `Dispatch<FooAction>`.  You get this:

```
// same type as Dispatch<FooAction>
interface DispatchFooAction {
    <T extends FooAction>(action: T): T;
}
```

So, now the question is: what *is* a `DispatchFooAction`?

Well, the interface has a single [call signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/callable), so it can be used as a function.  Let's look at the signature: `<T extends FooAction>(action: T): T`.

That is a [generic function](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) signature whose type parameter `T` must be assignable to `FooAction` (or whatever `A` is specified in `Dispatch<A>`); it takes a parameter of type `T` and returns a value of the same type.

---

Let's see if we can implement and use a `Dispatch<FooAction>`:

```
// good implementation
fooDispatcher = <T extends FooAction>(a: T) => a; // okay

const x = fooDispatcher({ type: "foo", foo: "" }); // okay, 
// T inferred as { type: string; foo: string; }, x is of that type

const y = fooDispatcher({ type: "foo", foo: "", baz: 1 }); // okay, 
// T inferred as { type: string; foo: string; baz: number; }, y is of that type

const z = fooDispatcher({ type: "foo" }); // error!
// missing foo prop --> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

interface BarAction extends FooAction {
    bar: string;
}

// bad implementation
fooDispatcher = <T extends BarAction>(a: T) => a; // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- bar missing in FooAction but required in BarAction
```

The good implementation works; `fooDispatcher` is a valid `Dispatch<FooAction>` because it's a function that takes an input of `FooAction` or any subtype of it, and returns the same type.  You can see that `x` and `y` call the function correctly, but `z` does not, because the input is not a valid `FooAction`.

The bad implementation doesn't work; `<T extends BarAction>(a: T)=>a` only claims to accept `BarAction` inputs, but `fooDispatcher` is required to accept *any* `FooAction`, and not every `FooAction` is a `BarAction`.

---

So, hopefully that makes some sense and that it helps you.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQMY2BAdgGhVgTzQ2zgF84AzKCEOAcigFMATAVwA96Aob4LGEyiUAhqiZwAIsADOYETFQALADzI4TDoKwsZKdJixwAvPiIHsAPkTc4duCoAqGrUx17klgBRiSWAFxwjgCUgY4A3NxkvAA2TPC+htJyCspCgcnyiqrEhpbhcAD0hRAA1iIE3HEJhLnYmalK6VKyWcoFxS0p2Wq1FliWVfFwAEYiLA3ZzZPKKjIwUPwA5vlFhRpQNFAAhNydWBA1+n5wALTnFxfWAH63d7z8gsJiEgBiEBB1RprauseGNnsVA+gXmiywS0i0SG8EoHxmTSgGVajRU70+-VWnTKFVsvE6MhEIAkMAIYAkIj0CLRHy+g0eQlE4i6bSU6K+iDgtnsThcvz07MxPn6YVCQSh+PWSw+LDgoDAcWJAgUhm4cIgCKEJgczh+bj+gr83hEopM1hEHXWOMq3FQ2HmcA42vVmqgXiQpPJgQAROrvXh1T7veRgpa4Na8Ht1s5+JQhMxZZTOZ6mKCFssCoG4GCM+Q8E7ZOHKHAYEoFCWyUxeHasA6CM74Sipm6PZWfX6AyC4N7-aMRAAvQIARhDYYjXM6Mawcc2rDgSdbXuz6Yhma7OdXfcHcCwbBAIyEBTIeHrhYgxdL5ZT1ft8H7DY1TbSLYrS99H2DZFDaw2W12nRAWQZGWYEIDgMAaDAM5ThuO44Pg25eAeARGReOAACERCgDk9XcOBDQBBBuTsMYkWXcFISiSU+1leVFTcGAVWwNVG26Z9tV5XC-kw7ChRNIJgjNecw3jaB-0KBD4Icc4+ygOBAJkYCITlIwCNIEY2HgZgAEc2GABMVIwrCvm4IA)

Comment: The example is great. I wonder how do you learn these kinds of stuff in the first place as I find some of the concepts are abstract to understand.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> export interface Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
>     <T extends A>(action: T): T
> }
> ```

This declaration is a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types). An equivalent declaration would be:

```
export type Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> =
    <T extends A>(action: T) => T
```

This, again, can be seen in the TypeScript docs: [Generic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types).

Therefore, this means:

> any function typed `Dispatch<A>` (where A is a free type variable of which concrete type shall extend `Action` and defaults to `AnyAction`) receives any value of which type (`T`) extends `A` and returns a value of the same type (possibly itself).

The important distinction between the type parameter in the type declaration (here `A`) and the function type declaration (here `T`) is that the former lets you specify which specific subtype the function implements or the caller should expect it to be, while the latter means the function should accept whatever type that satisfies the constraint and the caller may assume it could accept any such type.